# illegal cyclic reference involving object models

Tags: scala, playframework

When I try to pass a list to the view page of a Play application I receive an error:

```
illegal cyclic reference involving object models
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

models.scala.html:

```
@(liValues: List[String])
@for(value <- liValues){
 <li>@value</li>
}
```

entry in routes files:

```
GET     /models/tictactoe                    controllers.ModelController.index
```

index method in ModelController.scala where I pass the values:

```
def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.models(List("Link1" , "Link2" , "Link3")))
}
```

Complete ModelController:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc._

/**
 * This controller creates an `Action` to handle HTTP requests to the
 * application's home page.
 */
@Singleton
class ModelController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  /**
   * Create an Action to render an HTML page with a welcome message.
   * The configuration in the `routes` file means that this method
   * will be called when the application receives a `GET` request with
   * a path of `/`.
   */
  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.models(List("Link1" , "Link2" , "Link3")))
  }

  def sj = Action {

      Ok(Json.toJson(List(1,2,3)).toString());

  }
}
```

it seems I'm not declaring the list value in the view page correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [DummyPlaceHolder.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/e34c8a0d56d9df755bd99663ef0cfed88656ce61/core/play/src/main/scala/models/DummyPlaceHolder.scala)

```
package models

/*
 * Empty placeholder object to make sure templates keep compiling (due to
 * imports in template files), even if projects don't have any models.
 */
object DummyPlaceHolder
```

is interfering with your `views.html.models` which also has `models` so the generated template `target/scala-2.13/twirl/main/views/html/models.template.scala` will have something like

```
import models._

object models extends ...
```

which causes illegal cycle. Try changing the name of your template from `views.html.models` to say `views.html.model`.